# systemd version 219 from CentOS 7 listening on random UDP port

Tags: centos, systemd, systemd-resolved

Why does `systemd-resolved` from `systemd` version 219 listen on one random UDP port?

One of my machines listens on port `58557` (CentOS 7 with `systemd` version 219).

```
sudo netstat -tunlp|grep -P '^Active|^Proto|systemd'
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address  State  PID/Program name
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58557  0.0.0.0:*               372/systemd-resolve
```

Another machine listens on port `52010` (also CentOS 7 with `systemd` version 219).

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address  State  PID/Program name
udp      768      0 0.0.0.0:52010  0.0.0.0:*               398/systemd-resolve
```

Once I reboot the machines, `systemd-resolved` listens on another UDP port.

I have a third machine, which runs Fedora 27 with `systemd` version 234. Here, `systemd` does *not* open a random UDP port.

As a side note, I have disabled `LLMNR`, both in `/etc/systemd/network/20-eth0.network` and `/etc/systemd/network/20-eth0.network`, so this can't be it. Also, `LLMNR` would open port 5355.

```
$ grep LLMNR /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
LLMNR=no
$ grep LLMNR /etc/systemd/network/20-eth0.network
LLMNR=no
```

Comment: I checked on Ubuntu 17.10 with systemd version 234. Here, `systemd-resolved` listens on port 5355. Running `nmap` against the port identifies it was `llmnr`, matching your expectations.

Comment: If you are worried, you can launch a known-good  copy of CentOS 7 with systemd 219 and see if the default behavior differs from what your box is is doing.

Comment: I ran `systemd-resolved` as an argument to `strace`. I noticed that the UDP port is not open from the start. It is only listed in `netstat`, once the first request to resolve a DNS name is done. My current guess is that the port is the port at which `systemd-resolved` receives the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to the question, I ran `systemd-resolved` in strace, while `watch[ing] netstat -tunlp`. I noticed that the port is only opened once I make the first request to resolve a DNS name.

I captured the traffic using `tcpdump -i eth0 -nn -w capture_file`, noted down the port I see in `netstat` and looked at the output using Wireshark. The filter in Wireshark is simple: `udp.port eq 37078` (using the previously noted down udp port).

I can confirm that the UDP port that is being opened by `systemd-resolved` is the port that is used to communicate with the DNS server.

Comment: Good investigation. It would be nice if this behavior was documented somewhere. For example `man systemd-resolved` mentions nothing about listening on a random port.

Comment: It's not _listening_, that not being meaningful for UDP for starters; and this is normal behaviour for proxy DNS servers.  They make back-end transactions with other servers, and use one or more UDP ports for that.